# Magento DataProvider not populating data for edit in form

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, uicomponent, adminform

I am creating a simple CRUD operation in admin panel using UI Component. While trying to edit an entry, the fields are not prefilled. However, I can see the dataProvider is providing data in JSON.
Below is my code:

**DataProvider.php**

```
<?php
namespace Samplemodule\Faq\Ui;
 
use Samplemodule\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $faqCollectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $faqCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $faqCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach ($this->collection->getItems() as $item) {
            $result[$item->getId()]['faq_form'] = $item->getData();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**faq_new_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form.samplemodule_faq_data_source</item>
                <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form.samplemodule_faq_data_source</item>
            </item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Faq</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">faq_form</item>
            </item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
            <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/faq/saveAction</item>
                </item>
            </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="samplemodule_faq_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">samplemodule\Faq\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">samplemodule_faq_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="faq/faq/saveAction"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="faq_form">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Faq Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="question">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="answer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answer</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq_form</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">answer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
                <dataScope>status</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Disable</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is how my grid looks while editing

[image: URL contains edit action]

I can also see the data coming to form. Below is the JSON response

```
{"*": {"Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {"types":{"dataSource":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/provider","provider":"faq_new_form.azguards_faq_data_source"},"input":{"extends":"faq_new_form"},"form.input":{"extends":"input"},"textarea":{"extends":"faq_new_form"},"form.textarea":{"extends":"textarea"},"select":{"extends":"faq_new_form"},"form.select":{"extends":"select"},"fieldset":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/components\/fieldset","extends":"faq_new_form"},"faq_new_form":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/form","provider":"faq_new_form.azguards_faq_data_source","deps":"faq_new_form.azguards_faq_data_source"},"html_content":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/components\/html","extends":"faq_new_form"}},"components":{"faq_new_form":{"children":{"faq_new_form":{"type":"faq_new_form","name":"faq_new_form","children":{"faq_form":{"type":"fieldset","name":"faq_form","children":{"question":{"type":"form.input","name":"question","dataScope":"question","config":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/element\/abstract","template":"ui\/form\/field","dataType":"text","label":"Question","formElement":"input","source":"faq_form","validation":{"required-entry":true}}},"answer":{"type":"form.textarea","name":"answer","dataScope":"answer","config":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/element\/textarea","template":"ui\/form\/field","dataType":"text","label":"Answer","formElement":"textarea","source":"faq_form","validation":{"required-entry":true}}},"status":{"type":"form.select","name":"status","dataScope":"status","config":{"component":"Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/element\/select","template":"ui\/form\/field","formElement":"select","caption":"-- Please Select --","options":{"enable":{"value":"1","label":"Enable"},"disable":{"value":"0","label":"Disable"}},"label":"Status","dataType":"text"}}},"config":{"collapsible":false,"label":"Faq Details","sortOrder":"20"}}},"dataScope":"data","config":{"namespace":"faq_form"}},"azguards_faq_data_source":{"type":"dataSource","name":"azguards_faq_data_source","dataScope":"faq_new_form","config":{"data":{"faq_form":{"id":"1","question":"What does the module do?","answer":"This is a simple faq module","status":"1","created_at":"2021-06-08 13:12:00"}},"submit_url":"https:\/\/magento2.test\/admin\/faq\/faq\/saveAction\/","params":{"namespace":"faq_new_form"}}}}}}}}}
```

Can someone provide an insight on potential reason the gird is not populating with data?

Comment: What's your table primary key column name?

Comment: Please check your data in DataProvider.php using print_r(). And also check your column key name.

Comment: id is the primary key. Doing print_r() prints correct record of the edited entry. Please check JSON above, it has all correct info

Comment: Have you try below code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Try this**

**DataProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace Samplemodule\Faq\Ui;

use Samplemodule\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    protected $loadedData;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $faqCollectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $faqCollectionFactory->create();
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $faqData) {
            $this->loadedData[$faqData->getData('id')] = $faqData->getData();
        }
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->loadedData);
        exit();
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```

**faq_new_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form.faq_new_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form.faq_new_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Faq Details</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">general_information</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Save</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/faq/saveAction</item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="faq_new_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Samplemodule\Faq\Ui\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">faq_new_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
              </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general_data">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Faq Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="question">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="answer">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Answer</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">answer</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">answer</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="status" formElement="select">
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Status</label>
                <dataScope>status</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <select>
                    <settings>
                        <options>
                            <option name="enable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Enable</item>
                            </option>
                            <option name="disable" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="value" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Disable</item>
                            </option>
                        </options>
                        <caption translate="true">-- Please Select --</caption>
                    </settings>
                </select>
            </formElements>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have any idea about this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/339587/save-custom-fields-on-add-to-cart-button-click?noredirect=1#comment480991_339587

Comment: @Msquare It did work, may I know what I was doing wrong? It would be helpful if you can provide an explanation to this?

Comment: @Dexter your data provider file doesn't need the faq_form key into an array and in your XML file source must be your column key name. you can compare both file change check what's changes I made.